# How to add repository and install TMSU in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, repository, search

The package [TMSU](https://github.com/oniony/TMSU) (preview [here](https://superuser.com/a/387651/2005)) information is done for Ubuntu [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Etmsu/+archive/ubuntu/daily) but trying to apply for Debian 9. 
I do the following but get the following

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tmsu/daily
[sudo] password for masi: 
 The most recent release of TMSU,  from the default branch of github.com/oniony/TMSU
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~tmsu/+archive/ubuntu/daily
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpwrucyxjm/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpwrucyxjm/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 0D2677362121AE21: public key "Launchpad PPA for TMSU" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.browser'
```

OS: Debian 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TMSU can be installed as follow:

Install and configure `go`

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar xvf go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv go /usr/local
```

Install TMSU

```
git clone https://github.com/oniony/TMSU.git
cd TMSU
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/your-username/TMSU
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
go get -u github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
go get -u github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse
make
make install
```

[git repo : compiling.md](https://github.com/oniony/TMSU/blob/master/COMPILING.md)